# Using dplyr::if_else() in R to change the time zone of POSIXct timestamps based on value of another variable

Tags: r, dplyr, timestamp, lubridate, posixct

I'm working with some timestamps in POSIXct format. Right now they are all showing up as being in the timezone "UTC", but in reality some are known to be in the "America/New_York" timezone. I'd like to correct the timestamps so that they all read as the correct times.

I initially used an `ifelse()` statement along with `lubridate::with_tz()`. This didn't work as expected because `ifelse()` didn't return values in POSIXct.

Then I tried `dplyr::if_else()` based on other posts here, and that's not working as expected either.

I can change a single timestamp or even a list of timestamps to a different timezone using `with_tz()` (so I know it works), but when I use it within `if_else()` the output is such that all the values are returned given the "yes" argument `in if_else()`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

x <- data.frame("ts" = as.POSIXct(c("2017-04-27 13:44:00 UTC", 
"2017-03-10 12:22:00 UTC", "2017-03-22 10:24:00 UTC"), tz = "UTC"), 
"tz" = c("UTC","EST","UTC"))

x <- mutate(x, ts_New = if_else(tz == "UTC", with_tz(ts, "America/New_York"), ts))
```

Expected results are below where ts_New has timestamps adjusted to new time zone but only when values in tz = "UTC". Timestamps with tz = "America/New_York" shouldn't change.

```
                   ts      tz                  ts_NEW
1 2017-04-27 13:44:00     UTC     2017-04-27 09:44:00
2 2017-03-10 12:22:00     EST     2017-03-10 12:22:00
3 2017-01-22 10:24:00     UTC     2017-03-22 06:24:00
```

Actual results are below where all ts_New timestamps are adjusted to new time zone regardless of value in tz

```
x
                   ts      tz                  ts_New
1 2017-04-27 13:44:00     UTC     2017-04-27 09:44:00
2 2017-03-10 12:22:00     EST     2017-03-10 07:22:00
3 2017-03-22 10:24:00     UTC     2017-03-22 06:24:00
```

Comment: There is a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291932/vectorised-time-zone-conversion-with-lubridate/48292065#48292065) that I came across on SO. There is also [another similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506513/adding-timezone-to-posixct-object-in-data-table). It seems that you can use only one time zone in a single vector. Since you are trying to convert time stamps to EDT, all time stamps end up becoming EDT time even when you are using an ifelse condition. This is my guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't answer your original question about why `with_tz` doesn't work with `if_else` but here is one workaround. We subtract 4 hours (difference between UTC and EST) where `tz == "UTC"`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

x %>%  mutate(ts_New = if_else(tz == "UTC", ts - hours(4), ts))

#                   ts  tz              ts_New
#1 2017-04-27 13:44:00 UTC 2017-04-27 09:44:00
#2 2017-03-10 12:22:00 EST 2017-03-10 12:22:00
#3 2017-03-22 10:24:00 UTC 2017-03-22 06:24:00
```

Or in base R

```
x$ts_New <- x$ts
inds <- x$tz == "UTC"
x$ts_New[inds] <- x$ts_New[inds] - 4 * 60 * 60
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up doing the reverse essentially. I changed all the "EST" rows to UTC using your code, then used `with_tz()` to change all the times to "America/New_York". This has the benefit of not only displaying the correct time values, but also storing a correct timezone value and accounting for daylight savings time.